# Why is this DIV duplicating?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am having trouble getting this banner image underneath my nab bar to fit right and also to respond to screen width. It seems the div i am using to set the banner background image is duplicated or something here is a screen shot...

[Duplicate DIV pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BTy4m.jpg)

This is the same image twice.

Here is my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
    <title>Vector Games</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.png" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="homecss.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <head>
    <style>
body{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 font-family: sans-serif;
}
header{
 background-image: url('cubes.png');
 width: 100%;
 padding: 15px 0;
 color: #49ac6f;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 20px;
}
a{
 text-decoration: none;
 color: inherit;
}
nav ul{
 background-color: #a2a2a2;
 overflow: hidden;
 color: white;
 padding: 0;
 text-align: center;
 margin: 0;
 -webkit-transition: max-height .4s;
 -ms-transition: max-height .4s;
 -moz-transition: max-height .4s;
 -o-transition: max-height .4s;
 transition: max-height .4s;
}
nav ul li:hover{
 background-color: #49ac6f;
}
nav ul li{
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 20px;
}
.handle{
 width: 100%;
 font-size: 24px;
 background: #a2a2a2;
 text-align: right;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 padding: 15px 10px;
 cursor: pointer;
 display: none;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 650px){
 nav ul{
  max-height: 0;
 }
 .showing{
  max-height: 21em;
 }
 nav ul li{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: left;
 }
 .handle{
  display: block;
 }
}
.banner{
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding-top: 1000px;
 background-image: url('banner1.png');
}
    </style>
    <body>

    
    
 <header>
        <h1>Vector Games</h1>
        <img src="logo.png" alt="logo"/>
    </header>
    
 <nav>
     <ul>
         <a href="#"><li>Home</li></a>
            <a href="#"><li>About</li></a>
            <a href="#"><li>Racing</li></a>
            <a href="#"><li>Arcade</li></a>
            <a href="#"><li>Strategy</li></a>
            <a href="#"><li>Puzzle</li></a>
            <a href="#"><li>Sport</li></a>
        </ul>
        <div class="handle">
        &#9776;
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="banner">
        
    </div>
    <script>
        $('.handle').on('click', function(){
            $('nav ul').toggleClass('showing');
        });
    </script>

    <div class="banner">
        
    </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Oh and also how would I be able to make the image underneath my nab bar responsive like i need it scalable like the navbar. Do i need to setup media queries?

thanks,
Trace

Comment: Ask one question at the time please, you won't get better answers by doing all in one :)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using:

> background-repeat: no-repeat;

in the header part of your style.

[w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-repeat.asp)

Answer (score 0):

in your `header` styles try:

```
background: url('cubes.png') no-repeat;
```

or

```
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

For your responsive background image you could try:

```
background-size: contain;
background-position: center;
```

For responsive image elements you can do something like:

```
img.responsive {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
}
```